# about the property of Fourier transform??

Tags: fourier-analysis

It is said that: $$F[\frac{df(x)}{dx}] = i\omega F(\omega)$$.  This expression depends on the initial definition of Fourier transform, yes? 
if I define Fourier transform as:
$$F(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int f(x)e^{i\omega x}dx$$ Then tha above expression will be $$F[\frac{df(x)}{dx}]=-i\omega F(\omega)$$ right?????

Comment: And there are other similar definitions, all of which change Fourier transform results slightly. [See the list here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms), for example, and notice the different columns, for various  FT definitions.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega) \, \mathrm e^{-i \omega x} \,\mathrm d\omega$$
so we have
$$f'(x) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\!\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega) \,\mathrm e^{-i \omega x} \,\mathrm d\omega \right)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}   (-i \omega) \, F(\omega) \,\mathrm  e^{-i \omega x} \,\mathrm d\omega$$

Hence the Fourier transform of $f'(x)$ is $\mathcal F\{f'(x)\}= -i \omega \, F(\omega)$.

Comment: That means my comment about the initial definition is right yes??

Comment: yes, it is right.